# Chaining Angular resolvers

Tags: angular

I've got this basic route set up like so,

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
        {
          path: '',
          resolve: {
            data: DataResolver,
            stuff: StuffResolver, // <-- This needs data from DataResolver
          },
          component: DashboardComponent,
        },
      ],
    ),
```

And I want to resolve things inside the "StuffResolver", but in order to do that I require the data from "DataResolver" first.
I can I go about chaining or setting a "resolve order" to my resolvers so that I always have the data I need?

Thank you

Comment: Use RxJS `switchMap` or `concatMap` and create a Resolver which fetches first from the Data source and then from Stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular [Router](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/operators/resolve_data.ts#L70) internally uses `mergeMap` operator so all resolvers are executed simultaneously. (It's seems logic because there is no defined order for object properties in Javascript.)

Create one Resolver with chained operators that fetches all data in the right order.